# Fedora 17 Performance Issues

Tags: linux, fedora, performance

I have a Dell Latitude E4310. I have Windows 7 and Fedora installed on it. I rarely use windows and I have been using fedora for a good 9 months now. Recently the performance on my machine degraded considerably. I got a hardware servicing done as well however it continues to worsen each day. What tools can I use to analyze and further resolve the problem?

I have ample of disk space > 30 GB unused.

Comment: Do you use KDE ?

Comment: I asked it because I had a similar problem... Try to disable the desktop indexation. It's called Nepomuk.

Comment: I am not sure what KDE is. New to linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do I diagnose a performance problem?

This question is too broad for this website, but I'll offer you the following tips only because I don't want you to feel like you're being blown off.

1. Consult the output of `top`. Look for processes that are consuming either a lot of CPU and/or memory resources
2. Check the output of `dmesg`, looking for any messages related to errors or anything that's failing
3. Check log files, specifically `/var/log/messages`
4. Make sure you're up to date, `yum -y update`
5. Exercise the system using [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/)

These are just a few of the things to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `top` to see which process consumes the more RAM/CPU. `iostat` can also be used to see which process uses your disk.